# Ubuntu 18.04.1 post installation problems

Tags: wireless, software-installation, 18.04, dependencies, broadcom

i am new to Ubuntu or any Linux distro, few days back i have installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside windows 8.1. Wifi is not working after installation i found a post here regarding broadcom driver problem and tried to install *bcmwl-kernel-source_*.deb* but failed due to *dkms* and other dependencies are not installed. I tried to install them and they need some other dependencies like *gcc*, *dpkg-dev*, *build-essestial*, etc. I tried to fix this problem by downloading manually from https://packages.ubuntu.com/ but dependency tree for each package is overwhelming and i'm afraid that would go on.
i tried *Keryx* tool but did not work. Reinstalled Ubuntu with all the check boxes ticked, no luck. Tried so many things mentioned here but nothing worked. I don't understand is it problem with my installation?. Is there some easy way to install all these missing packages? Please suggest. Currently i have friend's PC running Ubuntu 16.04 if that would help in any way.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Console log

```
sudo apt install ./bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bcmwl-kernel-source : Depends: linux-libc-dev but it is not installed
                       Depends: libc6-dev but it is not installable
 dkms : Depends: gcc but it is not installable
        Depends: dpkg-dev but it is not installable
        Depends: make but it is not installable or
                 build-essential but it is not installable
        Recommends: fakeroot but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Wireless:

```
> lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network 08:00.0 Network controller [0280]:
> Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev
> 01)   Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0611]  Control: I/O-
> Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR-
> FastB2B- DisINTx-     Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr-
> DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-    Latency:
> 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes  Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 0    Region
> 0: Memory at c2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
>   Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel modules: wl
```

Comment: Don't download them manually, install them like this: `sudo apt install gcc` etc.

Comment: showing package gcc is not available.

Comment: You didn't say what you used to install the packages; `dpkg` the default took requires all dependencies to be pre-installed, but `apt` will detected needed dependencies & if they are found in your 'sources' will download & install them too.  You need a pathname for `apt` to recognize you want to install a file, so `apt install  ./filename.deb` may be easier than `apt install` followed by `dpkg`, but it's up to you.  Full error messages copied & pasted in your question allow us to answer you more helpfully.

Comment: Do you have the install DVD? The dependencies can be installed easily from there.

Comment: Have you loaded the repository (software) lists since install, ie. `sudo apt update` (which downloads & updates your local software repository lists; which does not mean software, just lists of software)?   It must be done otherwise it only knows what was on the install media.

Comment: @guiverc earlier i used dpkg now i tried with how you suggested. please find the log in question.

Comment: @chili555 no i don't. i downloaded from official website and made a bootable USB from that.

Comment: @guiverc yeah tried that too. problem is wifi not working here.

Comment: Is a DVD a possibility? The process is fast and easy if so.

Comment: @chili555 i could try that but isn't it same? ISO from official website will be burned to either a USB or DVD?

Comment: The iso is the same. However, we can add the DVD as an apt repository and install bcmwl-kernel-source and all its dependencies from the DVD quite easily. On the other hand, the process to do the same with the USB is unclear and a bit experimental. I will propose a DVD answer in a few moments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that all of the packages are on the install DVD. Insert the DVD and run:

```
sudo apt-cdrom -m -d /media/cdrom add
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

You will also probably need to disable secure boot, if applicable.

Post any errors or warnings.

Comment: I have connected to Ethernet and reinstalled Ubuntu again now everything is fine except wifi. I installed *bcmwl-kernel-source* still wifi doesn't work. Here is the log.   *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c2400000-c2407fff*

Comment: details regarding wifi vendor and driver are updated in the question.

Comment: What is the response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl`

Comment: *ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available*. This is what I got, saw the same error when I was installing *bcmwl-kernel-source*

Comment: Please note that the error will be extinguished, the driver will load and the wireless will, more than likely, work, if you disable secure boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: Awesome! If my answer has been helpful, please accept it. The searchers will appreciate it. https://askubuntu.com/tour